# Spacing added works in Firefox but not Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to add in space to compensate for the height of the **navbar** in Twitter Bootstrap 3. I'm doing this by adding in

```
<br>
```

While this line break appears in Firefox, it does not appear in Safari or Chrome. Full code can be found here https://github.com/srohrer32/beamformer/tree/gh-pages, under **index.html**. I'm asking how to either fix this problem in Chrome and Safari, or a better way to scale all of the links within the page up by a fixed `px` value so the **navbar** doesn't obscure some of my content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<br><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

probably `<br/>` will work? :)
You should have ending slash for every tag